# Firebase Issue with Observation Once a user sign in/up iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever user signs in/up to the app, some Firebase observations, such as fetchSavedActionsForTracking() and fetchActionsForDowns() (see the full functions below), do not observe during clicking buttons and the app acts weird like mixing up with nodes in Firebase.  As soon I compile the code again, the code works perfect and everything returns normal.  I am not sure if Xcode causes this issue or I have many observations in View Controller.  If someone experience the same problem or have an idea, please let me know.  I have also couple of observations in other VC but they are fine

Here is the observations I have I'm View Controller:

```
func fetchProperties() {

    // Added the first property
    Database.database().reference().child("Properties").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictinaryProperty = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

            // Assign property to Property()
            self.property = Property()

            // set the variables in dictionaryProperty's value to property's value (Be carefull the names have to match)
            self.property?.setValuesForKeys(dictinaryProperty)

            // User ID in Firebase
            self.property?.keyID = snapshot.key

            // Then add it to arrayPropertys
            self.arrayPropertys.append(self.property!)

            // This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)


    // Remove
    Database.database().reference().child("Properties").observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictinaryProperty = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

            // Assign property to Property()
            self.property = Property()

            // set the variables in dictionaryProperty's value to property's value (Be carefull the names have to match)
            self.property?.setValuesForKeys(dictinaryProperty)

            // User ID in Firebase
            self.property?.keyID = snapshot.key

            // Check on the loaded tracking
            if self.arrayPropertysTracking.isEmpty != true {

                // Then delete from Firebase
                self.checkingAndDeletingTracking(remove: self.property!)
            }

            // Then add it to arrayPropertys
            self.arrayPropertysRemoved.append(self.property!)

            self.removedProperties()

            // This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)

    // Child is edited
    Database.database().reference().child("Properties").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictinaryProperty = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

            // Assign property to Property()
            self.property = Property()

            // set the variables in dictionaryProperty's value to property's value (Be carefull the names have to match)
            self.property?.setValuesForKeys(dictinaryProperty)

            // User ID in Firebase
            self.property?.keyID = snapshot.key

            // Check if the updated property exists in Tracking window and if it does update it too
            if self.arrayPropertysTracking.isEmpty != true {

                self.checkingAndUpdateTracking(update: self.property!)
            }

            // Then add it to arrayPropertys
            self.arrayPropertiesEdited.append(self.property!)

            self.editedProperties()

            // This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)


}
```

Second;

```
// Load saved actions of the current user
func fetchSavedActionsForTracking() {

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    if let actualUserID = userID {

        // Add the first property
        Database.database().reference().child("Actions For Tracking").child(actualUserID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            // The key is the property owner's ID
            let keySnapshot = snapshot.key as? String

            // Tags of saved buttons
            let valueSnapshot = snapshot.value as? String

            if let actualKey = keySnapshot {

                 self.arraySavedKeyIDs.append(actualKey)

            }

        //This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })


        }, withCancel: nil)

        // Removed the saved actions in Firebase when a property delected in Tracking window
        Database.database().reference().child("Actions For Tracking").child(actualUserID).observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in

            // The key is the property owner's ID
            let keySnapshot = snapshot.key as? String

            // Tags of saved buttons
            let valueSnapshot = snapshot.value as? String

            if let actualKey = keySnapshot {

                self.arrayRemovedTags.append(actualKey)

            }

            // Remove the tag from the array
            self.removedArrayTags()

            // When saved is clicked twice clear the arrayRemovedTags
            self.arrayRemovedTags.removeAll()

            //This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }

}
```

Third;

```
 // Load properties from tracking window
func fetchTracking() {

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    if let actualUserID = userID {

        Database.database().reference().child("Tracking").child(actualUserID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictinaryProperty = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

                // Assign property to Property()
                self.property = Property()

                // set the variables in dictionaryProperty's value to property's value (Be carefull the names have to match)
                self.property?.setValuesForKeys(dictinaryProperty)

                // Then add it to arrayPropertys
                self.arrayPropertysTracking.append(self.property!)

                // This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }

        }, withCancel: nil)

        // Remove
        Database.database().reference().child("Tracking").child(actualUserID).observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictinaryProperty = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

                // Assign property to Property()
                self.property = Property()

                // set the variables in dictionaryProperty's value to property's value (Be carefull the names have to match)
                self.property?.setValuesForKeys(dictinaryProperty)


                // Then add it to arrayPropertys
                //self.arrayRemovedTracking.append(self.property!)

                // Remove the property from arrayPropertysTracking
                for remove in 0...self.arrayPropertysTracking.count-1 {

                    if self.arrayPropertysTracking[remove].keyID == self.property?.keyID {

                        self.arrayPropertysTracking.remove(at: remove)

                        return

                    }
                }

                // This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
}
```

Forth:

```
 // Fetch the down button actions
func fetchActionsForDowns() {

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    if let actualUserID = userID {

        // Add the first property
        Database.database().reference().child("Actions For Downs").child(actualUserID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            // The key is the property owner's ID
            let keySnapshot = snapshot.key as? String

            // Tags of saved buttons
            let valueSnapshot = snapshot.value as? String

            if let actualKey = keySnapshot {

                self.arrayDownsKeyIDs.append(actualKey)

            }

            //This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })


        }, withCancel: nil)

        // Removed the saved actions in Firebase when a property delected in Tracking window
        Database.database().reference().child("Actions For Downs").child(actualUserID).observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in

            // The key is the property owner's ID
            let keySnapshot = snapshot.key as? String

            // Tags of saved buttons
            // let valueSnapshot = snapshot.value as? String

            if let actualKey = keySnapshot {

                self.arrayDownsRemoved.append(actualKey)

            }

            // Remove the action from the array
            self.removeActionsForDownsFunctions()

            // When saved is clicked twice clear the arrayRemovedTags
            self.arrayDownsRemoved.removeAll()

            //This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }

}
```

Fifth;

```
func fetchAnsweresOnDowns() {

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    if let actualUserID = userID {

        Database.database().reference().child("Answers for Downs").child(actualUserID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictinaryProperty = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

                // this will empty the variables in downedProperty
                self.answerDowns = Property()

                // set the variables in dictionaryProperty's value to property's value (Be carefull the names have to match)
                self.answerDowns?.setValuesForKeys(dictinaryProperty)

                // Type
                self.answerDowns?.downID = snapshot.key

                // Then add it to arrayPropertys
                self.arrayAnswerDowns.append(self.answerDowns!)

                // Do not upload unless cell has been clicked
                if self.isExpanded == true {

                    // Upload into received downs
                    self.uploadeReceivedDowns(receive:self.arrayPropertys[(self.selectedIndex?.row)!])
                }


                // This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }

        }, withCancel: nil)

        // Removed property from answers on downs
        Database.database().reference().child("Answers for Downs").child(actualUserID).observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictinaryProperty = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

                // this will empty the variables in downedProperty
                self.answerDowns = Property()

                // set the variables in dictionaryProperty's value to property's value (Be carefull the names have to match)
                self.answerDowns?.setValuesForKeys(dictinaryProperty)

                // Type
                self.answerDowns?.downID = snapshot.key

                // Then add it to arrayPropertys
                self.arrayRemovedAnswerDowns.append(self.answerDowns!)

                self.removeAnswerDownsFunction()

                // This will crash because of background thread, so lets use DispatchQueue.main.async
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }


}
```

Here the viewDidLoad() function for the main view controller:

```
verride func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    // User is not logged in 
    checkIfUserIsLogedin()

    // The delegate for receiving an action/data and notifying the viewcontroller
    // The datasource is to feed an object such as a tableview and piker from the viewcontroller
    tableView.delegate = self      // Notify the ViewController whenever the user tabs on rows or scroll
    tableView.dataSource = self    // The dataSource will ask the ViewController for table cells

    // Initialize ref
    ref = Database.database().reference()


    // Creates UINib documents(i.e it create the the files created by main.storyboard or simailiar and truning them to a file)
    let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


    // Set up the search bar 
    searchBarSetup()

    // This function has to be here to reload table view with added property (i.e refresh table)

    fetchProperties()

    fetchSavedActionsForTracking()

    fetchTracking()

    fetchActionsForDowns()

    fetchAnsweresOnDowns()

}
```

and here is where I check if the user is logged in or not (Also exists in the main view controller):

```
func checkIfUserIsLogedin() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        perform(#selector(handleLogout), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
        //handleLogout()
    }
}

func handleLogout() {

    // When User click logout
    do {

       try Auth.auth().signOut()

    } catch let logoutError {
        print(logoutError)
    }

    // Object of loginViewController

    loginVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")

    // Transition to loginViewController()
    present(loginVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```

Here is the authentication (I have it in separate view controller)

Sign in:

```
// Sign in into Firebase
func handleLogin() {

    // Unwrap the text fields using guard which will simply do if-statament
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else {
        print("is nil")
        return
    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, err) in

        if err != nil {
            // There is an error
            if email == "" || password == "" {

                print("Empty")
                // Create an alert message
                let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Empty Fields", message: "Please Fill The Fields", preferredStyle: .alert)

                // Attach an action on alert message
                alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }))
                // Display the alert message
                self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return
            }

            print("Wrong Email or Password")
            // Create an alert message
            let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong Email or Password", message: "Please try again", preferredStyle: .alert)

            // Attach an action on alert message
            alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))
            // Display the alert message
            self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return

        }
        // Sueccessful
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Login sueccessful into Firebase database")
    }

}
```

Registering:

```
func handleRegister() {

    // Unwrap the text fields using guard which will simply do if-statament
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text else {
        print("is nil")
        return
    }

    // Upload the user's name and email into authentication
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user: User?, error) in

        if error != nil {
            // Handle the error (i.e notify the user of the error)
            if email == "" || password == "" || name == "" {

                print("Empty")
                // Create an alert message
                let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Empty Fields", message: "Please Fill The Fields", preferredStyle: .alert)

                // Attach an action on alert message
                alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }))
                // Display the alert message
                self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return
            }


            else if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {

                switch errCode {
                case .invalidEmail:

                    print("invalid email")
                    // Create an alert message
                    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Email", message: "Please check the entered email address", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    // Attach an action on alert message
                    alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }))
                    // Display the alert message
                    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

                case .emailAlreadyInUse:

                    print("in use")
                    // Create an alert message
                    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Existed Email", message: "The email existed in our database, login instead of registering", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    // Attach an action on alert message
                    alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }))
                    // Display the alert message
                    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

                case .weakPassword:

                    print("password is weak")
                    // Create an alert message
                    let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Password is weak", message: "Use upper and lower characters along with numbers", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    // Attach an action on alert message
                    alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                        alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }))
                    // Display the alert message
                    self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

                default:
                    print("Other error!")
                }

            }
        }

        // Get the user id from Firebase
        guard let uid = user?.uid else {
            return
        }


        // Successfully authenticated

        //Upload the name and user's ID into Database
        let usersReference = self.ref?.child("Users Info").child(uid)

        let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
        //self.ref?.child("User1").setValue(values)

        // Will add valuse without overwriting
        usersReference?.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

            if err != nil {
                print(err)
                return
            }

            // Transition to home screen
            self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Saved user successfully into Firebase database")
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the viewDidload() in the logging View controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // initialize the constraints of the white view and stack view
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    emailTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    passwordTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Create a varaible ref for Firebase
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    // You have to add the text field delegate if you want to add fuctions when user press/finish typing. For example when "return" key press, hide the keyboard
    self.nameTextField.delegate = self
    self.emailTextField.delegate = self
    self.passwordTextField.delegate = self
```

Comment: When are you calling these functions and when are you authenticating the user?

Comment: hey Jen, I am calling them the moment the user sign in/up.  I have another view controller asks user to sign in/up.  I just added the authentication into the post.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Can you also include your viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, if they include any code? Because my initial thought is you're presenting the login VC over the other VC after the first one loaded, so the listeners might be registered before the user is actually logged in. But that's just a guess since I don't have the code.

Comment: Sure, I just added them into the post.

Answer (score 0):

in `viewDidLoad()`, the code checks if the user is logged in, but then calls

```
fetchProperties()

fetchSavedActionsForTracking()

fetchTracking()

fetchActionsForDowns()

fetchAnsweresOnDowns()
```

whether or not the user is logged in. If the user is logged out, then presumably you need to press some button that calls `handleLogin()`. But this doesn't call those five functions again, so the data isn't updated to reflect the current user. Essentially, you want to make sure those functions are called after a user is logged in. There are lots of different ways you could achieve this, but for example:

Call functions if user is logged in upon loading app

```
func checkIfUserIsLogedin() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        perform(#selector(handleLogout), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
        //handleLogout()
    } else {
        fetchProperties()

        fetchSavedActionsForTracking()

        fetchTracking()

        fetchActionsForDowns()

        fetchAnsweresOnDowns()        
    }
}
```

And then call functions when user logs in if they weren't originally logged in

```
func handleLogin() {
   ...
   ...
   // Successful
   fetchProperties()

   fetchSavedActionsForTracking()

   fetchTracking()

   fetchActionsForDowns()

   fetchAnsweresOnDowns() 

}
```

Comment: Hey Jen, thanks for this.  It did not work.  The two functions that do not observe are fetchSavedActionsForTracking() and fetchActionsForDowns().  They suppose to listen whenever I click a button, which upload data into Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

After looking on logging View Controller I found that I am dismissing the logging view controller.  What solves my problem is the segue (Which I am not 100% sure why.)  I made segue from logging view controller to tab bar view controller and works beautifully!

I would appreciate any explanations on why the segue solves this problem.

Thanks Jen for your help!